# Too many $routeProvider routes in one file, how can I refactor this code?

Tags: angularjs, express, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I was looking for ideas about how to wire up Angular with Express + Node and [this article](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-express) was a tremendous help. The fact that I could do:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

And still be able to serve my Angular templates from that same `views` directory was a massive revelation for me since I had all along been under the assumption that all Angular templates went into the `public` directory. This is made possible by:

```
app.get('/templates/:name', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.params.name;
    res.render('templates/' + name);
});
```

Where `templates/` is a subdirectory of `views`. However, the code at the front end is not quite as slick:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/createPost', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/createPost',
      })
      .when('/readPost/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/readPost',
      })
      .when('/updatePost/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/updatePost',
      })
      .when('/deletePost/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/deletePost',
      })
  }]);
```

Those routes above are in charge of displaying a `post` resource. If I wanted to add, say, `author` and `category` resources, this file will obviously get a lot of boilerplate code with all those new routes having to be accounted for. In Express, for example, I can do this:

```
app.use('/posts', posts);
app.use('/authors', authors);
app.use('/categories', categories);
```

How can I do something similar in Angular or at least group the front end routes into related chunks?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the repeating parts of your code into a function, and then use that function to build your routes for each resource. Perhaps something like the following: (note that this is not tested, but should give you a good idea)

```
function routeResources(provider, resources)
{
    for( var i = 0, len = resources.length; i < len; i++)
    {
        var resource = resources[i];

        provider
        .when('/create' + resource {
            templateUrl: 'templates/create' + resource
        })
        .when('/read' + resource + '/:id/' {
            templateUrl: 'templates/read' + resource
        })

        // etc. etc. repeat for each route
    }
}
```

Then inside of your config function:

```
routeResources($routeProvider, ['Post','Author','Category']);
```

Comment: This is quite useful. But isn't this function assuming that all routes will have the same number of parameters, with `/create`, `/read`, `/update`, and `/delete` being paths that won't change across resources (which is highly unlikely)?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. From reading your question, It sounded to me like these routes would be repeating for each resource.

Comment: Not quite. Paths and the number of their parameters will be different for each resource. What about a service, would I be going in the right direction if I attempted to encapsulate this functionality in a service instead?

Comment: Sure, you could use a service.